# Why does this API call to Wikipedia show the Extracts for only a few results?

Tags: javascript, html, css, wikipedia-api

There is a property called extracts which gives you the summary for WikiPedia pages. It can be obtained by adding &prop=extracts in the url call. I am accessing an array of results, and I observe that only few results has the extract and the rest don't. It is usually either the first or the last result.

Here is the sample code

```
$.getJSON("https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&format=json&prop=extracts&gsrlimit=15&generator=search&origin=*&gsrsearch=" + searchTerm, function(data){
        console.log(data);
        $.each(data.query.pages, function (i) {
        console.log(data.query.pages[i].extract);
});
      });
```

Here is a screenshot of the console results 
[image: Part of the Console Result]

As you can see the extract property is missing for all the search results except the first one. Why is it so? And how do I correct this issue?

Okay so after referring to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9846795/prop-extracts-not-returning-all-extracts-in-the-wikimedia-api) and the documentation. I made this call

```
$.getJSON("https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&format=json&prop=extracts&exintro=1&excontinue=1&exlimit=max&gsrlimit=10&generator=search&origin=*&gsrsearch=" + searchTerm, function(data){
console.log(data);
    $.each(data.query.pages, function (i) {
  console.log(data.query.pages[i].extract);});});
```

Now the extracts for all the results are shown except the first and the last one.

Comment: Have you seen this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9846795/prop-extracts-not-returning-all-extracts-in-the-wikimedia-api

Comment: Tried the solution out, doesn't work at all. I read up the documentation to get an idea and updated the question.

Comment: Query continuation works differently these days but that's indeed the problem. See [docs](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Query#Continuing_queries).

Answer (score 0):

While clicking around in the Wikipedia API sandbox, I got the text extracts to work by adding the `exintro=1` property to the query.

So in your example, the code would be

```
$.getJSON("https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&format=json&prop=extracts&generator=search&redirects=1&formatversion=latest&exintro=1&origin=*&gsrsearch=" + searchTerm, function(data){
    console.log(data);
    $.each(data.query.pages, function (i) {
    console.log(data.query.pages[i].extract);
    });
});
```

Here's a link to the API sandbox version of the query. There are also options to limit the length of the extract, and explanations for what the properties do, etc.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special:ApiSandbox#action=query&format=json&prop=extracts&generator=search&redirects=1&formatversion=latest&exintro=1&gsrsearch=pants